# Why I can't access child property in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a typescript code:

```js
export interface SelectQuery_thing {
  __typename: "ThingQueryPayload";
  content: (SelectQuery_thing_content | null)[];
  pageInfo: SelectQuery_thing_pageInfo;
}

export interface SelectQuery_thing_content {
  __typename: "Thing";
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

And I wanna access name at a function :

```js
const itemToString = (data: SelectQuery_thing) => data && data.content && data.name
```

But I got:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'SelectQuery_thing_content[]'

How can I access name?
```

Comment: When you interface this way is `name` under `content`?

Comment: Where is `SelectQuery_thing[]` ?

Comment: I fix the error, I mean SelectQuery_thing_content[]

Comment: name is a property of the items in content which is an array on data, you're accessing name as though it's a property of data... which name do you want if content is an array?

Comment: I need print all names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data.name does not exists, because it is `SelectQuery_thing`, but `data.content` does.
The data.content is `SelectQuery_thing_content[]`, which is an `array`.
To access `.name` you need to index the array first, like:

```
data.content[index].name;
```

I would check the length of the array before indexing.

If you want to check, if all of the names exist, then you can use every();

```
data.content.every(val => !!val.name);
```

all together

```
const itemToString = (data: SelectQuery_thing) => 
                       data && data.content && 
                       data.content.length > 0 && 
                       data.content.every(val => !!val.name);// or (({name}) => !!name)
```